# Iterate over local Map in ssh shell script

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, ksh

I have a testFile having two parameters separated by pipe.

```
vi testFile
1|A
2|B
3|C
4|D
5|E
```

I am creating map and running it in a for loop, below is working:

```
while IFS='|' read -r NUM CHAR
do
        export MAP[$NUM]=$CHAR
done < testFile

for i in ${!MAP[@]}
do
        echo "$i  ${MAP[$i]}"
done
```

But when I am going ssh to any machine and running the loop, getting 
`./test.sh[11]: syntax error at line 20: '!' unexpected`

Below is not working

```
ssh  someUser@someHost << EOF

for i in ${!MAP[@]}
do
        echo "$i  ${MAP[$i]}"
done

EOF
```

How do I use MAP in ssh machine

**NOTE testFile is not fixed file, i am creating this file from sql query which is varying at every run.**

Comment: Is `someUser`'s login shell ksh?

Comment: @muru: yes, its s ksh shell `/usr/bin/ksh`

Comment: $ sign is interpreted by here string, try escaping it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this;

```
#!/bin/ksh
while IFS='|' read -r NUM CHAR
do
        export MAP[$NUM]=$CHAR
done < testFile

for i in "${!MAP[@]}"
do
        echo "$i  "${MAP[$i]}""
done

ssh  someUser@someHost <<EOF
eval `typeset -p MAP`

for i in "\${!MAP[@]}"
do
        echo "\$i  "\${MAP[\$i]}""
done

EOF
```

eval : evaluated server-side

typeset: to permit modifying the properties of variables.

\$ : escape a variable

Test :

```
$ ksh test.ksh
1  A
2  B
3  C
4  D
5  E
user@localhost's password: 
1  A
2  B
3  C
4  D
5  E
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir, I am getting `-ksh: syntax error at line 1: `(' unexpected` error after the changes done as per your suggestion.

Comment: Line:1 :#!/bin/ksh could u change #!/usr/bin/ksh. Or delete this line

Comment: I was not using #!/usr/bin/ksh., but after using it getting the same error.